# Blob Shadow effect using raycast on a jumping player (2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow, raycasting

I have a player that jumps on platforms. I need a simple blob (circle) shadow under the player. I could've made a child object with a pre-made image of a shadow and attached it to the player, but the player can jump, so this won't work. Can I achieve this using Raycast? Enable the shadow object only when the raycast hits a 2DCollider and enable it at the end position where the raycast hit? If yes, then how can I do that? The project is 2D.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```c#
public GameObject shadow;
public GameObject player;

private void Update()
{ 

    RaycastHit hit;

    Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.down, out hit);

    shadow.transform.position = hit.point;
    shadow.transform.LookAt(hit.normal);
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I just edited the post. I've tried that, but it doesn't work

Comment: There are quite a few misconceptions in your code. You need to use the Physics2D raycasting stuff for 2D colliders, but even if "normal" raycasting would work, thats not how you do it. Also `-Vector3.down` is actually a unit vector pointing upwards. I would strongly recommend you go over the official tutorials (and be it only the physics stuff), they are quite well made. Tutorials: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/2d-game-creation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html